# Why no PACT is returned when calling path /pacts/provider/<name>/for-verification

Tags: pact, contract, pactflow

I have a strange issue, I am creating a 2nd pact for consumer A, the first provider is B, and now I just uploaded the pact for provider C. The issue is that although I see the pact on the UI, when the curling/calling.

Using:

pact for junit5 4.6.3

pact-broker 2.110.0-pactbroker2.107.1

https://brokerurl/pacts/provider/C/for-verification

I see this

```
{"_embedded":{"pacts":[]},"_links":{"self":{"href":"https://brokerurl/pacts/provider/C/for-verification","title":"Pacts to be verified"}}}
```

I dont know what the issue is as I upload the contract from the same class in the consumer side.

Any ideas?

```
import au.com.dius.pact.consumer.MessagePactBuilder
import au.com.dius.pact.consumer.dsl.PactDslJsonBody
import au.com.dius.pact.consumer.junit5.PactConsumerTest
import au.com.dius.pact.consumer.junit5.PactTestFor
import au.com.dius.pact.consumer.junit5.ProviderType
import au.com.dius.pact.core.model.PactSpecVersion
import au.com.dius.pact.core.model.annotations.Pact
import au.com.dius.pact.core.model.messaging.Message
import au.com.dius.pact.core.model.messaging.MessagePact
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.jacksonObjectMapper
import com.traderepublic.schemas.avro4k.resolve.core.ConversationCreatedEvent
import com.traderepublic.schemas.avro4k.resolve.core.CustomerCreatedEvent
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import kotlin.test.assertNull

@PactConsumerTest
class TestPactConsumerTest {
    @Pact(
        provider = "B",
        consumer = "A",
    )
    fun bAsyncEvent(builder: MessagePactBuilder): MessagePact {
        val body =
            with(PactDslJsonBody()) {
                uuid("id")
                `object`("context")
                    .uuid("correlationId")
                    .closeObject()
                `object`("payload")
                    .uuid("id")
                    .closeObject()

                return@with this
            }

        return builder.expectsToReceive("create B created event")
            .withContent(body)
            .toPact()
    }

    @Test
    @PactTestFor(
        pactMethod = "bAsyncEvent",
        providerType = ProviderType.ASYNCH,
        pactVersion = PactSpecVersion.V3,
    )
    fun bCreatedAsyncEventTest(messages: List<Message>) {
        val testObjectMapper = jacksonObjectMapper().registerModule(JavaTimeModule())

        val message =
            testObjectMapper.readValue(
                messages.single().contentsAsString(),
                CustomerCreatedEvent::class.java,
            )

        assertNull(message.context!!.trigger, "If the trigger is not set, it should be null")
    }


    @Pact(
        provider = "C",
        consumer = "A",
    )
    fun cCreatedAsyncEvent(builder: MessagePactBuilder): MessagePact {
        val body =
            with(PactDslJsonBody()) {
                uuid("id")
                `object`("payload")
                    .uuid("Id")
                    .closeObject()

                return@with this
            }

        return builder.expectsToReceive("create C created event")
            .withContent(body)
            .toPact()
    }

    @Test
    @PactTestFor(
        pactMethod = "cCreatedAsyncEvent",
        providerType = ProviderType.ASYNCH,
        pactVersion = PactSpecVersion.V3,
    )
    fun cCreatedAsyncEventTest(messages: List<Message>) {
        val testObjectMapper = jacksonObjectMapper().registerModule(JavaTimeModule())

        val message =
            testObjectMapper.readValue(
                messages.single().contentsAsString(),
                ConversationCreatedEvent::class.java,
            )

        assertNull(message.context, "If the context is not set, it should be null")
    }
}
```

I also tried use a random name for the new service C like (test-provider) and I get the same error, so I am wondering if the issue is the name of the expectation. Please any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found that the query for the latest pact searchs for `main` branch on the pact_publications `"branch_heads"."branch_name" AS "branch_name"`.

Here is the full query:

```
SELECT "pact_publications".* FROM (SELECT "pact_publications".*, "branch_heads"."branch_name" AS "branch_name" FROM "pact_publications" INNER JOIN "pacticipants" AS "consumers" ON ("pact_publications"."consumer_id" = "consumers"."id") 
INNER JOIN "branch_heads" ON (("pact_publications"."consumer_version_id" = "branch_heads"."version_id")
# The issue was on this inner join on the second conditional
AND ("consumers"."main_branch" = "branch_heads"."branch_name")) WHERE (("pact_publications"."provider_id" = 15) AND ("pact_publications"."consumer_id" IN (SELECT "pacticipants"."id" FROM "pacticipants" WHERE (("name" = 'resolve-core-ticket-service-async') AND ("pacticipants"."id" IS NOT NULL)))))) AS "pact_publications" INNER JOIN "latest_pact_publication_ids_for_consumer_versions" AS "lp" ON ("lp"."pact_publication_id" = "pact_publications"."id")
```

Long story short, if you dont tag it with `main`, it won’t return it. This break a bit the flow we thought for onboarding an application but we found a workaround.

Also if you main branch is `master` you might need to update your CI or run a command to update the main branch of a pacticipant.

`pact-broker create-or-update-pacticipant --name Foo --main-branch dev`